# Transpose row values into specific columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a df like this:

```
    MemberID FirstName LastName ClaimID  Amount    
0   1          John      Doe     001A    100
1   1          John      Doe     001B    150
2   2          Andy      Right   004C    170
3   2          Andy      Right   005A    200
4   2          Andy      Right   002B    100
```

I need to transpose the values in the 'ClaimID' column for each member into one row, so each member will have each Claim as a value in a separate column called 'Claim(1-MaxNumofClaims), and the same logic goes for the Amount columns, the output needs to look like this:

```
    MemberID FirstName LastName  Claim1 Claim2  Claim3 Amount1 Amount2 Amount3     
0   1          John      Doe     001A   001B    NaN    100     150     NaN
1   2          Andy      Right   004C   005A    002B   170     200     100
```

I am new to Pandas and got myself stuck on this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the operation you need is not **transpose**,  this swaps row and column indexes
- this approach `groupby()` identifying columns and constructs `dict` of columns that you want values to become columns 1..n
- part two is expand out these `dict`.  `pd.Series` expands a series of `dict` to columns

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    MemberID FirstName LastName ClaimID  Amount    
0   1          John      Doe     001A    100
1   1          John      Doe     001B    150
2   2          Andy      Right   004C    170
3   2          Andy      Right   005A    200
4   2          Andy      Right   002B    100   """), sep="\s+")

cols = ["ClaimID","Amount"]

# aggregate to columns that define rows,  generate a dict for other columns
df = df.groupby(
    ["MemberID","FirstName","LastName"], as_index=False).agg(
    {c:lambda s: {f"{s.name}{i+1}":v for i,v in enumerate(s)} for c in cols})

# expand out the dicts and drop the now redundant columns
df = df.join(df["ClaimID"].apply(pd.Series)).join(df["Amount"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=cols)
```

|  | MemberID | FirstName | LastName | ClaimID1 | ClaimID2 | ClaimID3 | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | John | Doe | 001A | 001B | nan | 100 | 150 | nan |
| 1 | 2 | Andy | Right | 004C | 005A | 002B | 170 | 200 | 100 |

Comment: This is so concise, very much appreciated! If you have time, could you please break down the code after the agg()? Seems like its a dict comprehension with 2 dictionaries but I am scratching my head trying to understand the order of operations. Also, what do C and S refer to? What is s.name?

Comment: there are two `dict` comprehensions,  outer comprehension is simpler to understand, just creating an aggregation instruction e.g. `{"ClaimID":lambda s: list(s}`. inner comprehension is the real work done which is building up **lambda** function.  for the series want it to return a dict that is what you see come out.  take. look at **df** before the `join()` to get a clear idea of what it's done

Comment: Yes, I am breaking down it into smaller pieces, thanks again!